# One page PDF crashes Chrome with PDF JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, pdf.js

I'm developing editor's form, and need a pdf downloader. So, when i'm downloading single page document, Chrome has crashed (it's ok in all other browsers, even in IE). I'm trying to simplify my app, and totally deleted all except downloader button and canvas, but problem is still with me. Also, i have tried to download document as URL and as plain binary code, but no effect.

And if was at least 1 breakpoint, it'll be ok. If i downloaded some page document, then rejected, and then download 1page, it'll be ok too.

Does anyone have some thoughts?

Sorry for my english =/

NOTE

Problem was solved, 18h ago fixed bug in pdfjs, just update your pdfjs build and all'll be ok.

Comment: In response to your edit: The bug was not in PDF.js, but in Chromium. If you're not using Chrome 32, then you don't need to do anything to get correct behavior of PDF.js.